# Python pip install local on cluster openssl issues

Tags: linux, python-3.x, openssl, pip, cluster-computing

I am trying to get python3 and pip installed as my own user on a cluster.

The make test fails with:

```
    FAILED (failures=1)
test test_dbm_dumb failed
7 tests failed again:
    test_dbm_dumb test_import test_mailbox test_os test_pathlib
    test_stat test_tarfile

Total duration: 9 min 21 sec
Tests result: FAILURE
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

THis is some other info that may pertain to the error

```
    INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
warning: building with the bundled copy of libffi is deprecated on this platform.  It will not be distributed with Python 3.7

Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel      
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma              
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter           
readline                                                       
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
atexit                pwd                   time
```

but I continued on anyways with make install.

It appears there are openSSL issues. Please see below:

```
  -bash-4.2$ python3 get-pip.py --user
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./tools/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Collecting wheel
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/wheel/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wheel
-bash-4.2$ python3 pip
python3: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$ ldd /home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe1796d000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /home/CAM/anesta/tools/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fc88093b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc88072b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc88050f000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc88014e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc88102f000)
```

So it appears openssl is installed. Why does the make test say that is doesn't have ssl? Additionally I have bzip2 installed and python says that is not found too.

There must be something I'm missing here.

Thanks,
Alex

EDIT: no SSL module installed in python

```
    -bash-4.2$ python3 -c "import ssl"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/CAM/anesta/tools/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

Comment: Do you have SSL **module**? Check with `python3 -c "import ssl"`. And the command is not `python3 pip`, it's `python3 -m pip`.

Comment: okay, yes, python3 -m pip does properly launch pip. However I still get the SSL error when trying to download a package i.e. cellranger. Also I updated the original post showing ssl is not installed

Comment: `/home/CAM/anesta/tools` is hardly a standard install location for openssl. Maybe Python (or pip) can't find it there?

Comment: yes, but the ldd command shows that I successfully pointed linux to the openssl path in /home/CAM/anesta/tools. Is there a place to edit where python specifically looks for it?

Comment: Why do you compile Python yourself? Is there no binary distribution? Anyway if you compile Python from source you need include files (development packages) in addition to libraries. Install include files and recompile Python.

Comment: I am working on a cluster and only have user access. The cluster does not have it's own python 3 install so I have to do everything from scratch. It's a pain in the ass, but it's for science! I am not sure how to include the development packages. Is there a place that lists what is necessary?

Comment: No, there is no definite list other then Python build scripts (`configure`, `Modules/Setup.dist`, `setup.py`). See [this q at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/21547). You have to download sources for all neccessary dependencies and collect include files into your own directories.